# Qual o contrário do .equals no C#?

Tags: banco-de-dados, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, orm

Estou fazendo um left Join onde eu quero pegar apenas o que tem na tabela da esquerda e não tem na da direita.

Estou utilizando o LINQ e o EntityFramework. 
Eu fiz um código que pega as semelhanças, segue abaixo:

```
var mQuery = from pessoa in clientes
                         from prod in produtos
                         on pessoa.grupo equals prod.grupo
                         Select New { pessoa.nome, prod.descricao }
```

Como eu disse, eu estou treinando LINQ e Entity. 
Eu queria um método que fizessem necessariamente o contrário do equals. 
Obs: o operador != não funcionou

Vlww

Comment: o linq não em left join direto, é preciso usar alguns recursos, como agrupar e colocar nulo onde não encontrar, aqui tem um exemplo que pode te ajudar: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Comment: O modelo que eu peguei é deste link. Meu problema não é com left join, que por sinal, funcionou. Mas com o método de comparar os objetos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei a resposta que procurava. Não existe um método que seja oposto ao .Equal. O nome do que eu procurava era Outer Left Join. O desafio era que eu eu queria utilizar unicamente a estrutura LINQ.

Segue abaixo:

```
var permissoesCliente = from permi in context.tabelaPermissoes
                    join aces in context.tabelaAcessos
                    on permi.CodigoPermissao equals 
                    aces.CodigoPermissao into tt
                    from tabelaTemp in pp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where tabelaTemp == null
                    select new { permi.CodigoPermissao };
```

ref: https://forums.asp.net/t/1896048.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o **except**

**Except** é o método de extensão LINQ que subtrai elementos de uma coleção. Por exemplo, isso removerá elementos das primeiras entidades(Lista1) que são elementos nas segundas entidades(Lista2) e que serão retornados como uma terceira entidade (Lista3).

```
var Lista3 = Lista1.Except(Lista2);
```

**Outro exemplo mais completo:**

```
int[] Lista1 = { 5, 3, 9, 7, 5, 9, 3, 7 };  
int[] Lista2 = { 8, 3, 6, 4, 4, 9, 1, 0 }; 

int[] Lista3 = Lista1.Except(Lista2).ToArray(); 

Console.WriteLine("Resultado:");  
foreach (int num in Lista3){  
  Console.WriteLine("{0} ", num);  
}
```

**Resultado:** 7 e 5.

**Lista1**: Resultado do select completo.

**Lista2**: Select com os dados que não devem aparecer.

**Lista3**: Resultado do método *except*, trazendo somente os dados diferentes da Lista2.

**Nota:** Esse operador é como se fosse um *not in*.

Comment: Eu teria que jogar os dados da tabela1 e da tabela2 em uma lista?

Comment: Você precisaria jogar os dados em um _array_.

Comment: Mas aí eu deixo de usar o LINQ e uso uma estrutura de listas comum, certo?

Comment: Você pode continuar utilizando o LINQ para realizar os seus select para trazer os dados para a Lista1 e Lista2.

Comment: se tiver que carregar um select grande e outro select grande, terá um impacto consideravel na performance...

Comment: Concordo @CypherPotato, não seria muito performático.

Comment: @CypherPotato, concordo. Mas o desafio aqui era necessariamente utilizar o LINQ. Estou treinando formas diferentes de fazê-lo. Por isso, outra maneira de execução, neste caso, não é muito interessante pra mim.